# Bounding distance between geodesics in manifolds with nonpositive curvature

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

This is a duplicate of a question at the stackexchange which was not [answered](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1328416/bounding-distance-between-geodesics-in-manifolds-with-nonpositive-curvature). I've recently read (in some notes by Mark Pollicott) the following related claims, which, although quite intuitive, I would like to see proven (and clarified).

> Let $M$ be a compact, connected Riemannian manifold of nonpositive curvature and let $\tilde{M}$ be its universal cover. Let $\sigma,\tau:[0,T]\to \tilde{M}$ be two unit speed geodesics. Then:
>
> (a) $d(\sigma(t),\tau(t))\leq d(\sigma(0),\tau(0))+d(\sigma(T),\tau(T))$, for all $0\leq t\leq T$
>
> (b) $d(\dot \sigma(t),\dot \tau(t))\leq d(\dot \sigma(0),\dot \tau(0))+d(\dot\sigma(T),\dot\tau(T))$, for all $0\leq t\leq T$

**Note**: In item (a), $d$ refers to the shortest-path distance induced by the Riemannian metric. In (b) there is a distance $d$ on $T\tilde{M}$, but there's no clarification for this on the notes I read, it might be the distance induced by the Sasaki metric or maybe $d(v,w)=\sup\{d(\pi(\phi_tv),\pi(\phi_tw)):\ t\in[0,1]\}$ (where $\phi_t$ is the geodesic flow on $T\tilde{M}$ and $\pi:T\tilde{M}\to\tilde{M}$ is the projection).

Comment: For (a) you can use that $d$ is convex for manifolds of nonpositive curvature to get a stronger statement. See Sturm (Probability measures on metric spaces of nonpositive curvature) or Ballman (Prop. 5.4. of "Lectures on spaces of nonpositive curvature").